# How to send multiple mails with same cc content, without spamming cc addresses?

Tags: java, email

I have a problem that I think is impossible to solve in java nor in some smtp server configuration.

Lets say I am sending an email to the list of recipients. Sadly, it should be dynamically altered for each recipient to have his first and last name correctly resolved in content, which makes multiple mails from one template.

I have a request, in that case, not to spam addresses that are inside the **cc** header, which means if I have 100 recipients inside **to** header, than **cc** addresses should receive only first message, not all 100.

I think it is impossible to pass **cc** header to all the recipients without sending a copy to **cc** addresses for each of those messages. Am I right?

Using **bcc** instead is not an option since it behaves differently (it is hidden from recipients).

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/156532/smtp-is-it-possible-to-cc-someone-without-sending-the-original) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Actually I have problem which is other way around. I would like not to send CC in 99 of 100 times, but I still want have that header field in each of the messages.

Comment: If you read it the thing they say is still interesting. You could just have the cc header but use `RCPT TO:` to send it to the actual recipient without sending it to the CC. Because, as they say SMTP doesn't really care about the headers.

Comment: Maybe SMTP server doesn't care about CC headers, but recipients do care about it. They want to know who was CC-ed. Thanks for the link anyway it is interesting.

Comment: Yes and that's why it's the solution. You can include the header in the email so the recipient will see it, but you can just omit to tell the SMTP server to send it to the person in CC (by not putting it in `RCPT TO:`) . recipient will have a cc line and the person in cc will not have an email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129371/discussion-between-sasa-and-litelite).